# Blank PHP page on windows server 2012

Tags: php, html, server, windows-server-2012

My PHP page is showing blank page when I try and run it on the server by calling the IP to the windows server and the directory to it, when I try and run HTML on the same server it works.

When I run it on Apache localhost it works perfectly as well!

Can someone tell me whats the problem?

Comment: this could be a permissions issue, run as an admin. I've seen that happen quite a few times.

Comment: I do run it as an admin but still same problem

Comment: *"when I try and run HTML on the same server it works"* - how are you accessing this as, `http://localhost` or `file:///`? and the file extension is?

Comment: I use an external HTML file like for example it has "alert("hello world") my HTML file works on server.
And I access the files by typing the server-ip/files

Comment: see if error reporting throws anything. You need to post your full cod in regards to what you just posted in comments.

Comment: you've been given an "answer" below, see that. Nothing that hasn't really been said in comments though.

Comment: When I try phpinfo on my windows it works perfectly! I just can't seem to find the problem

Answer (score 0):

yeah, check the apache logs! probably your error reporting is off, it might be setting in your php.ini file (you can run php --ini to see files being used if you have shell access to server), just remember, there might a separate php.ini file used for running php shell from with command and separate for when it's run through web, just remember, get the right php.ini - this will show you errors :) and then you can see whats wrong with your app... on a linux server logs should be in /var/logs/httpd(or apache2 depending on your version)

btw. check this one http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I can't seem to find the php.ini anywhere in my files inside the server